# jQuery, weird focus behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, tagging

[image: my 2 tag forms]

Here is the problem. I have multiple tag forms in my page. They are supposed to be independent but there's a weird behaviour. If i write in the first form or do any other action and then i press the "X" on a tag of the second form, it doesn't noticed i'm working on a different form. I try to explain it better: if i press X while working in a form,

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

return the correct id. The same code returns a wrong id if i press X while working on the other form. Obviously it returns the id of the form I'm working on.

I think the problem is related to some weird focus condition (the keyboard is on a form while the mouse pointer click in another form). How am i supposed to solve that?

EDIT: form's html

```
 <form>

<input id="tagbox_infodisc_discussion_65" class="tag_field" object_type="infodisc_discussion" object_id="65" owner="Infodisc" owner_id="1" cancreatetag="1" canaddtag="1" canremovetag="1" value="['hi mom','efaefea']" $type="text" style="display: none; "><div id="tagbox_infodisc_discussion_65_tagsinput" class="tagsinput"><span class="tag"><span>hi mom&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span><span class="tag"><span>efaefea&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href="#" title="Removing tag">x</a></span><div id="tagbox_infodisc_discussion_65_addTag"><input id="tagbox_infodisc_discussion_65_tag" value="" data-default="" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); " class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"></div><div class="tags_clear"></div></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Just to clarify... In the situation where you're working in a form different from the one you're clicking on, it always returning FormA, or is it always returning the other form (FormB when working in FormA, FormA when working in FormB)?

Comment: @nachito it return the form i'm working on. in this example, if i had just wrote the tag "tag 2" and then i press on "hi mom", it will return the id of the form containing "tag 2". The correct id would be the id of the form containing "hi mom", because that's the id i should consider for removing the tag.

Comment: @AlexPeattie what should i post? it's not really important what the remove function does, because the problem is before that. I just bound a function to the click action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('input').live('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).prop('id'));
});
```

Comment: Actually, it may be `#id` or `.class`

Comment: it return "undefined". i used $('input') instead of form because the id is in the input. I'm gonna edit the first post with the html of this form.

Comment: mmm prop('id') is wrong, i think you meant attr('id').

anyway with $(this).parent().parent().attr('id') i can access the id of the input field, the cross has no id.